# JQuery UI- live is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I am trying to use JQuery UI with JQuery version 1.7.2
When I add the UI Javascript to my HTML Head, I get the following in the Firefox error log:

```
Timestamp: 5/05/2013 6:22:57 PM
Error: TypeError: jQuery(...).live is not a function
Source File: xxx/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-core/js/wp-e-commerce.js?ver=3.8.8.5.571548
Line: 237
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Your plugin probably workes with an older version of jQuery, either download an older version of jQuery UI or change the `live` line to `on`

Comment: The JQuery UI should work with JQuery 1.6 and above. I am running 1.7. I haven't even access any functions of the UI yet- simply including it throws the errors. Without it, those functions work fine.

Comment: Try playing with the order of items you link in the header, maybe you linked to UI before jQuery or something like that?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you use .live()?

Answer (score 0):

- live function removed in version 1.9
- you need jQuery Migrate plugin
  http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: I am not using version 1.9 though, I am using 1.7.2. I added the above but it didn't change anything.